# Correct way to implement inline assembler in c++ for xor operations on variables

Tags: c++, assembly, inline, xor

I've recently seen an article on how the swap operation can be performed using xor'ing instead of using a temporary variable. When I compile code using `int a ^= b;` the result won't simply be(for at&t syntax)

```
xor b, a
etc.
```

instead it will load the raw values into registers, xor it and write it back.
To optimize this i want to write this in inline assembly so it only uses three ticks to do the entire thing and not 15 like it does normally.

I've tried multiple keywords like:

```
asm(...);
asm("...");
asm{...};
asm{"..."};
asm ...
__asm ...
```

None of that worked, either giving me a syntax error, gcc doesn't seem to accept all of that syntax or else saying

```
main.cpp: Assembler messages:
main.cpp:12: Error: too many memory references for `xor'
```

Basically, I want to use the variables defined in my c++ code used in the assembler block, using three lines to xor them and then have my swapped variables basically like this:

```
int main() {
    volatile int a = 5;
    volatile int b = 6;
    asm {
        xor a,b
        xor b,a
        xor a,b
    };
    //a should now be 6, b should be 5
}
```

To clarify:
I want to avoid using the compiler generated mov operations since they take more cpu cycles than just doing three xor operations which would take three cycles. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that in assembly? `a ^ b; b ^ a; a ^ b;` would do the same.

Comment: Seriously, just use `std::swap(a,b);` and don't try to outsmart the compiler. Many architectures have a dedicated [exchange instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xchg), and otherwise it usually is much faster to copy into a temporary register.

Comment: *Why*? Just write clean readable C++ and let your compiler take care of generating the correct optimized asm (It will probably do a better job than you could anyway). Remember to turn on your compilers optimizer.

Comment: Because even when using g++ -O3 it will still be around 15 lines for the three xor operations and not 3.
Normally, the values are loaded into the registers first from stack pointers, then xor'd and written back to memory. Just takes too long for use in microcontrollers since the speed is limited there.

Comment: In your code the `volatile` forces the operands and result of each operation to be read/written from/to memory for each line. Why are `a` and `b` `volatile` in your example?

Comment: @chtz Because if I don't declare them volatile g++ -O3 will simply use the constant values instead of actually doing the xor operation. This obviously wouldn't be needed for the final program, it's just there for clarification.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Oxz-0V ... the problem is, that gcc does recognize it's the "swap" operation, and it rewrites it in machine code with faster variant using `mov` instructions and temporary registers, it will refuse to emit the less optimal `xor` variant. So this is just demonstration how to get -O3 actually do something sensible, but not to remove all your code. If you write wrong C++, there is no point to "optimize it by inline assembly", that's the last step, not first. And if you want to toy with assembly, like you want actually the slow `xor` swap, then use rather standalone assembly.

Comment: @Ped7g Apart from the fact that g++ seems to take more lines to do the same, 6 lines are still more than 3 so how can double the operations be less efficient?
EDIT: Plus, I need the c++ integration for the project it's integrated in.

Comment: @TheSupremeGod All lines (instructions) are not equal. Some take more CPU cycles than others. A longer (number of lines) solution can *easily* be faster than a shorter one.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But xor lines are one operation just as mov are, especially if the vectoring isn't used. Or am I wrong here? Both are integrated cpu instructions aren't they?

Comment: @TheSupremeGod 1 asm instruction is *Not* the same as 1 CPU cycle. Some instructions take tens, hundreds (or more) cycles to complete. Some take just a few. You *cannot* measure efficiency by just counting the number of instructions.

Comment: What processor are you doing this on? x86 and friends cannot read/write to multiple memory locations in the same instruction (that's what the error message `too many memory references` means). At least one operand must be a constant or a register.

Comment: *"Or am I wrong here?"* unfortunately on so many subtle details, that it's very difficult to give you some short meaningful answer. Your understanding of x86 architecture is at like 5%, so you are wrong about pretty much everything, including the assumption the `xor` solution would be 3 lines long ... but in subtle way, that you are almost right, and each of those details would take quite some explaining, in the end it would be like writing you a small book about how to performance-optimize for x86 CPUs. Luckily such books already do exists, it will just take time to read and comprehend them.

Comment: Also ... it's not like you are doing it completely wrong, the issue is, that 8086 is now 40+ years old, and the modern variants of x86 CPUs are very complex machines themselves, while many beginners information makes first sure you learn basics, and the `xor` trick was essential historically on some platforms, where avoiding extra register was better, as the memory access was similarly slow as CPU itself. So your whole approach is generally correct, you just didn't see all of it yet... (and there's a LOT to be seen)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use inline assembly, you should use [`__asm__ volatile`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm). However, this type of optimization may be premature. Just because there are more instructions does not mean the code is slower - some instructions can be *really* slow. For example, a floating point BCD store instruction (`fbstp`), while admittedly rare, takes over 200 cycles - compared to one cycle for a simple `mov` (Agner Fog's [Optimization Guide](https://www.agner.org/optimize/) is a good resource for these timings).

So, I implemented a bunch of "swap" functions, some in C++ and some in assembly, and did a bit of measuring, running each function 100 million times in a row.

---

## Test cases

#### `std::swap`

`std::swap` is probably the preferred solution here. It does what you want (swap the values of two variables), works for most standard library types and not just for integers, clearly communicates what you are trying to achieve, and is portable across architectures.

```
void std_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    std::swap(*a, *b);
}
```

Here is the generated assembly: It loads both values into registers, and then writes them back to the opposite memory locations.

```
movl    (%rdi), %eax
movl    (%rsi), %edx
movl    %edx, (%rdi)
movl    %eax, (%rsi)
```

#### XOR swap

This is what you were trying to do, in C++:

```
void xor_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    *a ^= *b;
    *b ^= *a;
    *a ^= *b;
}
```

This doesn't directly translate to only `xor` instructions, because there is no instruction on x86 that allows you to directly `xor` two locations in memory - you always need to load at least one of the two into a register:

```
movl    (%rdi), %eax
xorl    (%rsi), %eax
movl    %eax, (%rdi)
xorl    (%rsi), %eax
movl    %eax, (%rsi)
xorl    %eax, (%rdi)
```

You also generate a bunch of extra instructions because the two pointers may *alias*, i.e. point to overlapping memory areas. Then, changing one variable would also change the other, so the compiler needs to constantly store and re-load the values. **An implementation using the compiler-specific `__restrict` keyword will compile to the same code as `std_swap`** (thanks to @Ped7g for pointing out this flaw in the comments).

#### Swap with temporary variables

This is the "standard" swap with a temporary variable (that the compiler promptly optimizes out to the same code as `std::swap`):

```
void tmp_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

#### The `xchg` instruction

`xchg` can *swap* a memory value with a register value - it seems perfect at first for your use case. However, it is *really* slow when you use it to access memory, as you will see later.

```
void xchg_asm_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    __asm__ volatile (
        "movl    (%0), %%eax\n\t"
        "xchgl   (%1), %%eax\n\t"
        "movl    %%eax, (%0)"
        : "+r" (a), "+r" (b)
        : /* No separate inputs */
        : "%eax"
    );
}
```

We need to load one of the two values into a register, because there is no `xchg` for two memory locations.

#### XOR swap in Assembly

I made two versions of the XOR-based swap in Assembly. The first one only loads one of the values in a register, the second loads both before swapping them and writing them back.

```
void xor_asm_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    __asm__ volatile (
        "movl   (%0), %%eax\n\t"
        "xorl   (%1), %%eax\n\t"
        "xorl   %%eax, (%1)\n\t"
        "xorl   (%1), %%eax\n\t"
        "movl   %%eax, (%0)"
        : "+r" (a), "+r" (b)
        : /* No separate inputs */
        : "%eax"
    );
}

void xor_asm_register_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    __asm__ volatile (
        "movl   (%0), %%eax\n\t"
        "movl   (%1), %%ecx\n\t"
        "xorl   %%ecx, %%eax\n\t"
        "xorl   %%eax, %%ecx\n\t"
        "xorl   %%ecx, %%eax\n\t"
        "movl   %%eax, (%0)\n\t"
        "movl   %%ecx, (%1)"
        : "+r" (a), "+r" (b)
        : /* No separate inputs */
        : "%eax", "%ecx"
    );
}
```

---

## The results

You can view the full compilation results along with the generated assembly code on [Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/DFj4-s).

On my machine, the timings (in microseconds) vary a bit, but are generally comparable:

```
std_swap:              127371
xor_swap:              150152
tmp_swap:              125896
xchg_asm_swap:         699355
xor_asm_swap:          130586
xor_asm_register_swap: 124718
```

You can see that `std_swap`, `tmp_swap`, `xor_asm_swap`, and `xor_asm_register_swap` are generally very similar in speed - in fact, if I move `xor_asm_register_swap` to the front, it turns out slightly slower than `std_swap`. Also note that `tmp_swap` is exactly the same assembly code as `std_swap` (although it regularly measures in as a bit faster, probably because of the ordering).

`xor_swap` implemented in C++ is slightly slower because the compiler generates an additional memory load/store for each of the instructions because of aliasing - as mentioned above, if we modify `xor_swap` to take `int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b` instead (meaning that `a` and `b` never alias), the compiler generates the same code as for `std_swap` and `tmp_swap`.

`xchg_swap`, despite using the lowest number of instructions, is *terribly slow* (over four times slower than any of the other options), just because `xchg` is not a fast operation if it involves a memory access.

---

Ultimately, you have the choice between using some custom assembly-based version (that is hard to understand and maintain) or just using `std::swap` (which is pretty much the opposite, and also benefits from any optimizations that the standard library designers can come up with, e.g. using vectorization on larger types). Since this is over one hundred million iterations, it should be clear that the potential improvement by using assembly code here is very small - if you improve at all (which is not clear) you'd shave off a couple of microseconds at most.

**TL;DR**: You shouldn't do that, just use `std::swap(a, b)`

---

## Appendix: `__asm__ volatile`

I figured that it may make sense at this point to explain the inline assembly code a bit. `__asm__` (in GNU mode, `asm` is enough) introduces a block of assembly code. The `volatile` is there to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize it away - it likes to just remove the block otherwise.

There are two forms of `__asm__ volatile`. One of them also deals with `goto` labels; I will not address it here. The other form takes up to four arguments, separated with colons (`:`):

- The simplest form (`__asm__ volatile ("rdtsc")`) just dumps the assembly code, but does not really interact with the C++ code around it. In particular, you need to guess how variables are assigned to registers, which is not exactly good.
- Note that the assembly code instructions are separated with `"\n"`, because this assembly code is passed verbatim to the GNU assembler (`gas`).
- The second argument is a list of *output operands*. You can specify what "type" they have (in particular, `=r` means "any register operand", and `+r` means "any register operand, but it is also used as an input"). For example, `: "+r" (a), "+r" (b)` tells the compiler to replace `%0` (references the first of the operands) with the register containing `a`, and `%1` with the register containing `b`.
- This notation means you need to replace `%eax` (as you would normally reference `eax` in AT&T assembly notation) with `%%eax` to escape the percentage sign.
- You can also use `".intel_syntax\n"` to switch to Intel's assembly syntax if you prefer.
- The third argument is the same, but deals with input-only operands.
- The fourth argument tells the compiler which registers and memory locations lose their values to enable optimizations around the assembly code. For example, "clobbering" `"memory"` will likely prompt the compiler to insert a full memory fence.  You can see that I added all the registers I used for temporary storage to this list.

Comment: Note that `xchg` is actually pretty fast if you use it to exchange the values in two registers.

Comment: note your C++ `xor_swap` source doesn't signal to the compiler that both pointers never alias, which would allow the compiler to avoid `xor` instructions completely and use mov-only variant of swap code... Try `void xor_swap(int * __restrict a, int *b)` instead to see how it collapses back into `std::swap` like code (putting pressure on the programmer to never call that with aliased same memory ... actually in the case of `swap` even calling it with aliased memory does produce "correct" result, as the same value is swapped with the same value, but generally) OP assumes two distinct variables.

Comment: @Ped7g Good point! Just tried that out, it actually generates exactly the same code as `std_swap`...

Comment: Your answer is actually great in showing `xor` variant. But if one is trying to be "fair", and use full C++ expertise, then OP assumes two different memory variables, so it's fair to let compiler know, and then the compiler shows better understanding of the machine, and avoiding slower `xor` variant completely. It's just very tricky to write correct C++ (giving the compiler the identical assumptions, which were used by the coder while writing assembly variant). Unfortunately, it's quite easy to write some (unoptimal) C++ and show better assembly and blame compiler, I did it many times too. :)

Comment: OP uses MSVC and his problem is that there is no `xor mem32, mem32`, see that `too many memory references for xor` message.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the work you put into that. I now see the differences I just have a few things left to understand. Firstly, why use `__asm__ volatile` instead of `asm{}` or `asm()`? Second, I now get why the error occurs and your `xor_asm` code illustrates the solution quite well, but still don't understand why they are similarly fast, if the amount of cpu operations differs? As far as i know, mov and xor take one cpu opt each.

Comment: @TheSupremeGod: `asm volatile` *is* pointless here.  It's a pure function of the inputs, and you want to let the compiler optimize it away if the output operands are unused.  Or to CSE multiple swaps of the same inputs.  Of course this is why you don't want inline asm for this in the first place; the compiler will already do a better job with `std::swap`.

Comment: (Actually `volatile` in this version might be a partial but insufficient workaround for the bugs in it: passing a pointer in a register to inline asm does *not* imply that the inline asm reads the pointed-to memory.  And with no `"memory"` clobber, gcc/clang will optimize away apparently-dead stores into the pointed-to memory, or at least reorder them with the asm. That's why you should use `"+m"(*a)` read/write memory operands.)  See [Informing clang that inline asm reads a region of mem](//stackoverflow.com/q/31628554) and [Looping over arrays with inline asm](//stackoverflow.com/q/34244185)

Comment: @TheSupremeGod: See also [How to write a short block of inline gnu extended assembly to swap the values of two integer variables?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45910530) for a version that just uses inline-asm input/output constraints to make the compiler do the swap, with no instructions.  But notice that it's still optimization-defeating because it breaks constant-propagation, and any value-range info the compiler had about the values.  It's a fun exercise in learning to use constraints, but 100% useless in real code. And in real life, you also often want the results still in regs, not back in mem.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay i forgot the volatile there, oops. I meat why use `__asm__ volatile()` instead of `asm volatile{}`, aka why the different variants? Are they compiler dependent?

Comment: @TheSupremeGod: oh.  `__asm__` is exactly equivalent to `asm` in GNU C, except that `asm` isn't a keyword with `-std=c++11/14/17`, only with `-std=gnu++11/14/17`.  `__asm__` is useful in headers that need to compile with code that uses strict ISO mode.  The manual documents this near the top of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html, right before the "Qualifiers" heading.  Semi-related: [What is the difference between 'asm', '\_\_asm' and '\_\_asm\_\_'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3323445)  `__asm` is the MSVC keyword.

Comment: Okay I understand now. But still, why is `xor_asm_swap` slower than `xor_asm_register_swap` if there are literally more instructions, considering that both `mov` and `xor` take the same amount of cpu operations.

Comment: @TheSupremeGod modern x86 can often execute two or three instructions at the same time in single thread, depends on the instruction type and arguments and their dependency. Modern x86 CPU, unless you are doing some intensive calculation based on register values, is usually rather throttled by the speed of memory than amount of instructions, as the CPU will be usually able to execute tens+ basic `mov/xor/...` instructions operating with registers between the choke points, so adding one/two more `mov` may be not visible on benchmark results, unless you create new bottleneck.

Comment: From the answer it is not clear what was benchmarked and how, which makes whole world difference with such simple and short pieces of code... whether there were swapped different locations of memory of 1+MiB buffer, from/to the same cache line or using two regions of memory, or if the same location was swapped all the time, how the loop around did look, etc... with such microbenchmarks all these details may seriously taint the final results, and it takes quite some expertise to benchmark anything synthetic properly. Also it never applies to real code directly, that must be profiled separately.